# Contract negotiation

Tags: recruitment, contractors

I have been put forward to an employee, by a recruiter, for 550 per day. After the interview they wanted to make me an offer but I said:

> Given the company and what I have heard, I want 650.

The recruiter said that:

> I can't negotiate at this stage since I have originally been put forward for 550.

Is this true/correct? My gut feeling is no. I found the job online for a rate of 600-700.

Comment: Why didn't you negotiate the rate with the recruiter before you went through the interview process?

Comment: That's a good question. I left it for later , i.e. have a conversation first and then see what happens.

Comment: You can always take the 550, and make sure the recuiter knows that you want 700 on contract renewal. It all depends on your current situation; is 550 a step down or a step up from where you are now?

Comment: It would depend greatly on "the company" and "what you heard."  Did you learn that the days will be longer hours than initially presented? (lots of overtime) - That's a legitimate concern.  If you find the company "distasteful," and you want more as compensation for that, then no, it would not be a legitimate concern.  You're either willing to work for them or not.

Comment: I'd terminate the relationship with the recruiter immediately. The only question would be whether I'd bother to ask  how they could behave so unprofessionally.

Answer (score 5):

You can negotiate at any point, as long as you are willing to walk away from the opportunity.

The recruiter is pushing you to accept the lower rate as they will gain their commission from representing you at an earlier stage.

In hindsight you should have gained an insight into the day rate range before applying.

Comment: Sure, I agree everything is negotiable. But I also think that for the right candidate, an employer would offer the rate he asks.

Comment: Given that they are willing to offer up to 700 I wouldn't think that there isn't room for negotiation.

Comment: @dqm: not necessarily. For example there may be budget constraints

Comment: @dqm: Regarding advertised rates, in my own role the salary was advertised as £25k-£40k. Now that I'm in it, I know it is £34k to £37k. So what you see is not necessarily what you get.

Comment: @dqm "But I also think that for the right candidate, an employer would offer the rate he asks." Don't count on that. There is enough room for bluffing before it gets near the point where the candidate would actually drop off.

Answer (score 2):

> The recruiter said that I can't negotiate at this stage since I have
>   originally been put forward for 550. Is this true/correct? My gut feel
>   is no.

I suspect you are correct here.

But it takes at least two sides to negotiate anything. So it's possible that the recruiter is correct and the other side will no longer negotiate. It's also likely that the recruiter doesn't want to have an uncomfortable discussion with the hiring manager ("You know that dqm you interviewed who was presented at 550? Now he wants more.")

The only way you will know is to ask.

But of course you are free to turn down the offer and find another gig.

Next time try to determine the rate you want before you are offered. Or tell the recruiter that you will only determine the appropriate rate *after* interviewing. Be aware that some recruiters won't be willing to work with you this way.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is set in stone at this point so yes you can negotiate (assuming you are prepared for a negative outcome of course). It is obviously much better to be put across at a rate you are happy with in the first place but since I'm guessing you don't have a time machine that's only a lesson that can help you for next time.

As for your current situation I would be wary of negotiating unless you can point to *specific* reasons as to why the rate you would like is higher now than when you were put across. Otherwise it can look underhanded - as if you were trying to merely bait their interest with the lower rate and had no intention of ever taking it. And in that case even if they agree to the new rate there is a good chance they won't be happy about it and that can impact how everything goes afterwards - think of it like going to a supermarket and seeing a loaf of bread advertised for £1, only when you get to the till they say "sorry the price went up while you were walking over, it's £1.50 now", if you really need the bread you will probably just pay the extra but you'll damn sure be complaining to everyone you know about it!

Were there any facts that came out in the interview to justify the rate increase? e.g. were they asking you to use some high-value skills from your resume that the original job description didn't include? That sort of thing. If there isn't anything like this that you can point to then really you erred in agreeing to be put forward at the lower rate and attempting to negotiate now probably isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 1):

Then it sounds like the recruiter put you forward at a rate you never agreed to. That's the recruiter's problem, not yours, as long as you (as answered elsewhere) are willing to walk away from it.

If, on the other hand, you told the recruiter that 550 was perfectly acceptable rate for you, and you're changing your tune because you think the company might be willing to pay more, then you can hold out, of course, but you're not treating your recruiter fairly, and they might pull you as a candidate and stop working with you. If they introduced you to the company, and later withdraw you, then the company likely will not want to work with you on the side (they'd still owe the recruiter a fee, and if a recruiter pulls a candidate, they'll likely trust the recruiter's judgment and view that as a "red flag").